# Complement of unit sphere is disconnected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have proved that unit sphere is connected in $\Bbb R^3$, can I use this fact to prove that complement of unit sphere is not connected?

Comment: There are connected subspaces of $\Bbb R^3$ whose complements are connected.

Comment: A set $X$ is connected in some topological space $(V,\tau)$ does not implies its complement is disconnected! Try to visualize your proof in case of $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you write the complement as the union of $\{x:||x\|<1\}$ and $\{x:||x\|>1\}$ which proves (from definition of connectedness) that it is not connected.

Note that $\{(x,y,z): x, y ,z \geq 0\}$ and its complement are both connected, so your argument does not work.

Answer (score 0):

No. Instead, try assuming for contradiction that there is a path $\gamma\colon I\to\mathbb R^3$ going from, say, $\mathbf 0$ to some $x\in\mathbb R^3$ with $|x|>1$. Then use a connectedness argument to show that the continuous map $|\gamma |$ (composite of $\gamma$ and the norm $|\cdot |$) must pass through $1$. This is sufficient.